# Connecting to container using ansible

Tags: ansible, containers

I have build a docker image and started the container using ansible.  I'm running into an issue trying to create a dynamic connection to the container from the docker host to set some environment variable and execute some script.  I know ansible does not use ssh to connect to the container where I can can use the expect module to run this command "ssh root@localhost -p 12345".  How do I add and maintain a connection to the container using **ansible** docker connection plugin or pointing directly to the docker host? This is all running in AWS EC2 instance.

I think I need to run ansible as an equivalent to this command use by ansible to connect to the container host "docker exec -i -t container_host_server /bin/bash".

---

- name: Create a data container
  docker_container:
   name: packageserver
   image: my_image/image_name
   tty: yes
   state: started
   detach: True
   detach: yes
   volumes:

  - /var/www/html
    published_ports:
  - "12345:22"
  - "80:80"
    register: container

Thanks in Advance,
DT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set environment variables you can use parameter "env" in your docker_container task.

In the docker_container task you can add the parameter "command" to override the command defined as CMD in the Dockerfile of your docker image, somethning like

```
command: PathToYourScript && sleep infinity
```

In your example you expose container port 22, so it seems you want run sshd inside container. Although it's not a best practice in Docker, if you want sshd running you have to start that using command parameter in the docker_container task:

```
command: ['/usr/sbin/sshd', '-D']
```

Doing it (and having defined a user in the container), you'll be able to connect your container with

```
ssh -p 12345 user@dockerServer
```

or, as for your example, "ssh -p 12345 root@localhost" if your image already defined root user and you are working on localhost.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.  I can "ssh -p 12345 user@dockerServer" manually to the container.  I want to use ansible to ssh to set the env variables and execute some script.

Comment: I also added env to the task to set the variable in the container but it seems not setting variable.

Comment: The easiest way is using https://www.ansible.com/ansible-container . After having installed it, you'll write 1) container.yml (very similar to the example you wrote) that generates a dynamic inventory and 2) main.yml that is your playbook. From here you can run any role you need.

Comment: Since I already have the tasks build docker image and running docker container to start applying ansible-container I need to use the 'ansible-container run' to orchestrate the current running container.  Will that work?

Comment: container.yml should begin with:version: "1"
services:
  packageserver:
     image: my_image/image_name
     ports:
.... The file main.yml should begin with: - hosts: packageserver than variables and roles. Running ansible-container build anf ansible-container run from the directory in the upper level should be run.

Comment: Trying to understand how to apply the ansible-container to work with the current playbook.  So far, 1) I've install ansible-container on the docker host where the packageserver container is running using ansible 2) Created the container.yml, main.yml in the ansible folder and the folder is located at root level of the repo 3) How/Where do I run the ansible-container init, run, shipit command and where in the main playbook does it goes?

Comment: Update from previous comment: 1) The container.yml and main.yml file contain the info suggested above by gile 2) Container with name packageserver is running 3) Ran the command "ansible-container run", got the following error "No DOCKER_HOST environment variable found. Assuming UNIX socket at /var/run/docker.sock" 4) DOCKER_HOST var is set "DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375" 5) DOCKER_OPTS property is set "DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"" in /etc/default/docker 6) Error from "ansible-conteiner run",

Comment: Error: No DOCKER_HOST environment variable found. Assuming UNIX socket at /var/run/docker.sock
0.3: Pulling from ansible/ansible-container-builder
8d30e94188e7: Pull complete
...
Digest: sha256:9e388109767033fe2dc539b3366a5fd09e137563b52ed2d7a4614c7e26aebbfe
Status: Downloaded newer image for ansible/ansible-container-builder:0.3
Attaching to ansible_ansible-container_1
Cleaning up Ansible Container builder...
Pulling repository docker.io/library/dt-ansible-container-packageserver
Error: image library/dt-ansible-container-packageserver:latest not found